# transition between components in reactjs not working and css properties not being applied

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router, css-animations

I have the following react component, that basically serves up all the other components , i wanted some animation between all the component trasitions, so now my component looks like so , I am using the `react-transition-group` ,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './surveyholder.css';
import Welcome from './../components/welcome/welcome';
import Generalinfo from './../components/generalinfo/generalinfo';
import Preferences from './../components/preferences/preferences';
import Navigation from './../UI/navigation/navigation';
import { Route , BrowserRouter , Switch } from 'react-router-dom'; 
import { CSSTransition , TransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';


class Surveyholder extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route render={ ({ location }) => (
          <div className="App">
            <Navigation />
            <TransitionGroup>
              <CSSTransition key={location.key}  timeout={3000} classNames="fade">
                <Switch location={ location }>
                  <Route path="/" exact component={ Welcome } />  
                  <Route path="/generalinfo" exact component={ Generalinfo } />
                  <Route path="/preferences" exact component={ Preferences } />
                </Switch>  
              </CSSTransition>    
            </TransitionGroup>          
          </div>
          )} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default Surveyholder;
```

So basically this works all fine , the components even tradition with the right class's I.E. the below:

```
.fade-enter {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: opacity 3s ease-in;    
  }

  .fade-enter.fade-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

However i don't see the transition animation , just a delay in the changing of the components , i don't see the fade animation. The css above is just not applied to the components (the classes are , the css properties are not , i slowed down the animation to 3 seconds to check this and found out.).

If you checkout the example in the doc's you will notice that the animation part is handled by toggling css classes [HERE](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/animated-transitions).

Why is my component transition animation not working ?

**P.S.** i have used the `eject` command in my app , so is there a reason my classes from `import './surveyholder.css';` are ot being imported properly and hence i am unable to see the classes in `Inspect element` -> `styles` in my dev tools ?

Comment: Can you please share your file structure?

Comment: It would be very helpful to have a working example on codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: @grammar not sure how to do that , here s github link , you can check it out by running `npm install` and then `npm start`.

P.S. check my comment below the answer down.

Comment: Github project link?

Comment: @GautamNaik --> https://github.com/gautamz07/cs-survey , sorry my bad

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since u are using css modules, the `.fade-enter`, `.fade-enter-active` class gets appended with unique identifier.

The react transition group searches for `.fade-enter`, `.fade-enter-active` class, but instead gets  `.fade-enter_unique_id`, `.fade-enter-active_unique_id` class.

In order to prevent this from happening, wrap ur css class in `:global(.classname)`

Add this to ur **surveyholder.css file**

```
:global(.fade-enter) {
  opacity: 0.01;
}
:global(.fade-enter-active) {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}
:global(.fade-exit) {
  opacity: 1;
}
:global(.fade-exit-active) {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}
```

And also update the timeout value in **surveyholder.js**,

```
 <CSSTransition key={location.key}  timeout={300} classNames="fade">
```

I tested this solution on ur project.

Comment: @Danm Thanks .. super awesome , will try this out ! Thanks alooot !

Answer (score 0):

You may be correct.  Since you ejected the create-react-app, you no longer are using the style-loader package.  Try to `npm install --save-dev style-loader`

Also in your webpack.config.js include this in your module object:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" },
          { loader: "css-loader" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

You should then be able to `import ./surveyholder.css` without problem.
See style-loader documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/style-loader)

Comment: tried your solution but it does't work for some reason. interestingly enough if i change the following line in my webpack.config.dev.js file `localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'` to just the following `               localIdentName: '[local]'` , it works fine , for obvious reasons, but that breaks from other component css styling !